# O servidor SMTP requer uma conexão segura ou o cliente não foi autenticado

Tags: c#, envio-de-email, smtp

Estou tendo o seguinte o erro, ao trabalhar com **`SMTP`** e **`MailMessage`** no C#:

> **O servidor SMTP requer uma conexão segura ou o cliente não foi autenticado. A resposta do servidor foi: 5.5.1 Autenticação solicitada Saiba mais em**

Ou em inglês

> **The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Servidor de E-mail
    /// </summary>
    protected SmtpClient SmtpClient { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Conteudo da Mensagem
    /// </summary>
    protected MailMessage MailMessage { get; set; }
    #endregion 

   /// <summary>
   /// Método enviar e-mail
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="smtp"></param>
   /// <param name="from"></param>
   /// <param name="to"></param>
   /// <param name="subject"></param>
   /// <param name="body"></param>
   /// <param name="priority"></param>
    public string EnviarEmail(string smtp, string from, string to, string subject, string body, bool priority)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            SmtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            SmtpClient.Port = 587;
            SmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            SmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("raffa.ferreiira@gmail.com","senha");
            SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            MailMessage = new MailMessage();
            MailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from, "Raffa Ferreira", Encoding.UTF8);
            MailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to, "Fulano teste", Encoding.UTF8));

            MailMessage.Subject = subject;
            MailMessage.Body = body;
            MailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            MailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

            if (priority == false)
            {
                MailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            }
            else
            {
                MailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            }

            SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage);
        }
        catch(SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mensagem : {0} " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch(SmtpException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mensagem SMPT Fail : {0} " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mensagem Exception : {0} " + ex.Message);
        }

        string mensagem = "E-mail enviado";
        return mensagem;
    }
```

O que estou fazendo de errado, eu entendi a mensagem do erro. 
Tentei trocar o **`e-mail`** e a **`senha`**, é a primeira vez que uso **SMTP** sou novo nisso. Sei que não é difícil, apenas uma falta de atenção minha.

Por enquanto já procurei algumas **helps** em outros lugares, mas não achei nada que me ajudasse, espero que possam me ajudar.

Comment: Você consegue *logar* no Gmail na mesma máquina onde está rodando isto? Torço muito para você não ter publicado sua senha pra todo mundo ver.

Comment: Não publiquei não, onde está "senha" é algo fictício. Eu acabei de logar com o mesmo e-mail e senha, e logou normalmente. Mas durante a execução do projeto, ele me tráz essa falha.

Comment: Quando você *loga* no Gmail, ele pede confirmação de acesso? Te indica uso fora do normal? Viu isto? https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity Tenteou mudar isto? https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Ele me apareçe algumas persmissões de acesso, Devices e PC's !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para utilizar o Gmail, `UseDefaultCredentials` deve ser `false`. Essa propriedade deve ser definida **antes** das credenciais, dessa forma:

```
SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
SmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("raffa.ferreiira@gmail.com","senha");
```

Você deve também permitir o acesso "menos seguro" ao seu Gmail, através da página [Aplicativos menos seguros](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado !

Comment: @RaffaFerreira ou fazer seu aplicativo usar XOAUTH, para nao precisar autorizar aplicativos menos seguros.

Comment: malditos "Aplicativos menos seguros."..era isso que tava dando de errado comigo.rs

Comment: Depois de muito rodar a Internet, finalmente essa era a causa. Ajudou muito mesmo!

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema e a solução estava no próprio gmail em autorizar aplicativos. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Caso prefira não permitir o acesso de aplicativos menos seguros, a seguinte solução pode ser adotada:

- Logado na conta do gmail que será usada pelo site selecione "Minha Conta"
- Selecione a opção "Login e segurança"
- Ative a "Verificação em duas etapas" (siga os procedimentos solicitados)
- Selecione a opção "Senhas de app" (siga os procedimentos solicitados)
- Selecione a opção "Selecionar app"
- Escolha a opção "Outro (nome personalizado)"
- Informe o nome do seu site / webapp
- Copie a senha gerada pelo google
- No trecho de código abaixo, informe a senha gerada ao invés da senha da conta:

  SmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("raffa.ferreiira@gmail.com","senha gerada pelo google");

Isto feito, seu webapp ou site estará habilitado a conectar na conta sem ser barrado pelo google security e sem reduzir o nível de segurança.