# Envio de email asp net - Gmail

Tags: c#, asp, email, smtp, gmail

Segue o código do envio de email, O erro informado é no acesso com o SMTP do google.

```
        StringBuilder conteudo = new StringBuilder();

    conteudo.Append("O Srº(ª) " + "<b>" + txtNome + "</b>" + " entrou em contato pelo site no dia " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " às " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "hrs" + "<br /><br />");
    conteudo.Append("<b>" + "Nome do contato: " + "</b>" + txtNome + "<br />");
    conteudo.Append("<b>" + "Email: " + "</b>" + txtEmail + "<br />");
    conteudo.Append("<b>" + "Telefone: " + "</b>" + txtTelefone + "<br />");
    conteudo.Append("<b>" + "Tipo do serviço: " + "</b>" + ddlServico + "<br />");
    conteudo.Append("<b>" + "Mensagem: " + "</b><br />" + txtMensagem);

    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(rnConfiguracoes.emailFrom, rnConfiguracoes.emailTo);
    msg.Subject = rnConfiguracoes.nomeDoSite;
    msg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.Default;
    msg.Body = conteudo.ToString();
    msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.CC.Add(rnConfiguracoes.emailCC);
    msg.Bcc.Add(rnConfiguracoes.emailBCC);

    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(rnConfiguracoes.emailSmtp);
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Port = 587;

    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(rnConfiguracoes.emailLogin, rnConfiguracoes.emailSenha);

    try
    {
        smtpClient.Send(msg);
        return "Mensagem enviada com sucesso. Agradecemos seu contato.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.StackTrace;
    }
```

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado?

Comment: E qual é o erro, jovem?

Comment: O SMTP do Google está impedindo estas conexões. Entre nas configurações e acione a liberação do envio externo.

Comment: Esta com problema na hora de enviar o email, Aonde eu libero isso andre? na minha propria conta?

Comment: Estou procurando onde vi isso. Foi em uma conta recém-criada.Você não recebeu nenhuma notificação na conta do gmail indicando que houve uma tentativa de envio por um agente externo?

Comment: Criei faz quase um ano, estou pegando o erro do StackTrace para mandar. um minuto!!

Comment: Segue o erro: O servidor SMTP requer uma conexão segura ou o cliente não foi autenticado. A resposta do servidor foi: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Comment: @DannySouza contas novas do google vem com Login por aplicações menos seguras desabilitado (isso inclui o uso de SMTP com senha). Ou o usuário libera isto no painel de controle da conta, ou melhor que isso, faça sua aplicação direcionar o usuário para uma autenticação por XOAUTH, para que ele autorize sua aplicação a acessar a conta, e gerando o token de acesso ao SMTP.

Comment: Denny Souza, Eu dei uma pesquisada e vi que já tinha uma pessoa que perguntou sobre o mesmo erro/problema que você está tendo aqui no stack e pelo que vi parece que conseguiu solucionar o problema, O link está aqui > http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90462/o-servidor-smtp-requer-uma-conex%C3%A3o-segura-ou-o-cliente-n%C3%A3o-foi-autenticado Espero que agora consiga resolver o seu problema, e não esqueça de classificar a resposta como resolvida depois. Boa Sorte.

Answer (score 1):

Há pouco tempo eu criei uma nova conta Google no gmail para usar um agente de aplicação para enviar mensagens. Na primeira tentativa de e-mail, a conta configurada recebeu uma notificação de impedimento do envio que redireciona sempre para esta tela:

[image: Tela de aplicativos menos seguros.]

A URL desta opção é, [Aplicativos menos seguros](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

O caso do suporte que explica isso está descrito [AQUI](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Esta parte da resposta está correta. Pra ficar completa a resposta, só falta explicar como fazer para usar o SMTP como aplicativo seguro (que é melhor do que diminuir a segurança).

Comment: Era isso mesmo, achei esse link no meu email.

Comment: @Bacco, acho que a Google ganha muito poder com esta opção e nós ficamos ainda mais seguros. Mas não acho que o SMTP com SSL fique menos seguro por ser enviado de uma aplicação "desconhecida". Mas é uma opinião pessoal.

Comment: @AndreMesquita a segurança não é no sentido de SSL ou não. O conceito é que como as pessoas usam o Google pra outras coisas, você deixar a aplicação (ou o desenvolvedor) ter a sua senha, implica acesso ao seu email, ao drive, ao hangouts e tudo o mais. Se a conta é sua mesmo, isso não tem problema. Mas como a senha do google passou a ser multiserviços, nem sempre é para "o cara do TI" ter acesso ao resto das coisas, como postar no Google+ ou mexer no Woogle Wallet. Aí entra o modelo novo de autenticação, onde o usuário autoriza separadamente as aplicações e os direitos delas.

Comment: @AndreMesquita Vou fazer um "ponto contra" defendendo seu ponto de vista: eu acho que a Google poderia muito bem deixar você criar uma senha separada para o SMTP, por exemplo, assim resolvendo o problema sem fugir da autenticação convencional. Mas aí não vai de encontro com a política de expansão da empresa ;)